# Insert close div (</div>) after an element using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have html structure like below:

```
<div class="address-container">
   <div class="address">
      AAAAA
   </div>
   <div class="address">
      BBBBB
   </div>
   <div class="address">
      CCCCC
   </div>
   .
   .
   .
</div>
```

I want it to use jquery, when it loop to certain element will append

```
"</div><div class='address'>"
```

. The structure should look like this:

```
<div class="address-container">
   <div class="address">
      AAAAA
   </div>
   <div class="address">
      BBBBB
   </div>
*</div>*
*<div class="address-container">*
   <div class="address">
      CCCCC
   </div>
</div>
```

My code is look like this:

```
$('div.address').each(function(i, e){
        var h = $(e).height();
        total_height = total_height + h;

        if(total_height >= 300){
            $(e).after('</div><div class="address-container">');
            total = 0;
        }
    });
```

But above code unexpectedly produce like this (it automatically open div for close div and close div for open div class="address-conntainer"):

```
<div class="address-container">
   <div class="address">
      AAAAA
   </div>
   <div class="address">
      BBBBB
   </div>
*<div></div>*
*<div class="address-container"></div>*
   <div class="address">
      CCCCC
   </div>
</div>
```

What's wrong with my code? Or you guys have other solution to produce html structure that I wanted? Any help is really appreciated :)

Comment: Why can't you just change the original HTML code?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that HTML code is parsed into DOM Objects. This means that in this case:

```
<div id="d_outer" class="address-container">
   <div class="address">
      AAAAA
   </div>
   <div class="address">
      BBBBB
   </div>
   <div class="address">
      CCCCC
   </div>
</div>
```

Object #d_outer contains three child objects. To transform it into

```
<div id="d_outer" class="address-container">
   <div class="address">
      AAAAA
   </div>
   <div class="address">
      BBBBB
   </div>
</div>
<div id="d_outer2" class="address-container">
   <div class="address">
      CCCCC
   </div>
</div>
```

you have to create a new div node #d_outer2 and move last child of #d_outer inside #d_outer2. Try something like this:

```
$('#parentAddressContainer div.address').each(function(i, e){
            var h = $(e).height();
            total_height = total_height + h;

            if(total_height >= 300){                
             $('#parentAddressContainer').append("<div class=\"address-container\"></div>")                
             $('#parentAddressContainer div.address-container:last-child').append($(e));
             total_height = 0;
            }
        });
```

Here is [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3b72m/).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by creating a new element and removing the old one once then document is ready.

**Original HTML**

```
<div class="address-container">
    <div class="address">
         AAAAA
    </div>
    <div class="address">
         BBBBB
    </div>
    <div class="address">
         CCCCC
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
var $target = $('.address-container .address');
var $container = $('<div/>').addClass('address-container');
var $elem = $('<div/>').addClass('.address').html($target.eq(2).html());
$container.append($elem);

$('.address-container').after($container);
$target.eq(2).remove();
```

**[Here is the JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ka9Mh/)**.